# Controlling number of results in Google Custom Search

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

I am using google custom search for my website, every search results in a big list of results. I want only limited number of results to be shown to the customer say first 10 so that he/she is not confused. Please help.

Comment: And if those first ten results don't include what the person's looking for?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that is only possible using the paid search. But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418009/google-custom-search-engine-cse-api), you may be able to intercept the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to hide the navigation like this:

```
.gsc-cursor-box {visibility: hidden;}
```

or

```
.gsc-cursor-box {display: none;}
```

You can use !important to force override the default attribute (if it already exists).