# Customizing Google Custom Search

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

I am using Google Custom Search for my site. I want Google to provide at most 2 searches from a site. I am not sure whether it is possible or not, but it seems there is no such option on Google CSE.

For example, my CSE has 10 listed sites. What I want is that whenever a user makes a search then search results should show at most two links from a site. In general CSE is returning  multiple results from one site only and these come on page 1. If it is at most 2 from a site then the user has a better chance to have links from other sites too.

Comment: What do you mean by _at most 2 searches from a site_ ?

Comment: For example my CSE has 10 listed sites, what I want is that whenever user makes a search then search results should show at most two links from a site. In general CSE is resulting multiple results from one site only and those comes on page 1, if it is at most 2 from a site then user has better chance to have links from other sites too.

Comment: Is this *really* a separate question from your [previous one](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31774/controlling-number-of-results-in-google-custom-search), or are you just trying again? You can edit the other one to clarify instead if so.

Answer (score 2):

Google Search works on particular algorithm system which provides search results on through web page. If you need just one result from one website then it’s not possible. You can block any particular website through Google custom search but it will provide results per pages or URL not on domain or website.